# How do you calculate the number of times to call $( '#el'' ).scrollTop( 1 ) to traverse a div height of 759?

Tags: javascript, html, function, scale, vertical-scrolling

**Update:**
I've created this [Code Page demo](https://codepen.io/howardb1/full/mdJMdQY) to show what I'm talking about.  This demo shows two methods, the first is the brute-force method and the second is Robert McKee's method.

With the first method, press the **Scroll to End** button to derive the vertical (y) scaling value, which is then shown next to the button that was just pushed.  The list of values below the buttons, you will also see the number of 1px scrolls horizontally and vertically needed to fully scroll to the lower-left corner of the scroll-area, shown in the **Scroll Y Count** and **Scroll X Count** fields.  With the scaling value now showing and the adjacent checkbox checked, pressing the **Scroll to End** button shows that the same number of 1px horizontal and scaled vertical scrolls now get to the lower-right end of the scroll-area.

With the second method, press the **Calculate Y Scale** button to calculate the y scale value without needing to actually scroll.  After the value is calculated the second dive is scrolled to show that it works.

The first method finds a y scale value that allow scrolling so that the horizontal and vertical scrolls over and down such that they both get to the left side and bottom with exactly the same number of scrolls.  I'm not sure why there is a difference, but the second method is very close, only one scroll different, so its good enough.

**Original Question:**

I need to calculate the scaling values needed to scroll the horizontal and vertical scrollbars of a div so that when the horizontal scrolling completely traverses the width of the div, the vertical scrolling also completely traverses the height of the same div.

I do this now by first manually counting the number of of calls of the `$( '#div' ).scrollLeft( ++x )` jQuery function and, separately, the number of calls of the `$( '#div' ).scrollTop( ++y )` function, with the x and y values starting at 0, and increasing by 1 per call, that are needed to scroll over the div's width and height, respectively.  In my case the div is **540** px wide by **759** px high, and it take **342** times to cover the width and **660** for the height.  From this I can calculate the y scaling value to put in the vertical scroll function call, `$( '#div' ).scrollTop( ++y * yScale )`, to be 660/342 for my div.  The issue is that the div's width and height aren't always the same so I can't use a pre-calculated value for the y scaling value for all possible contents that the scrolling div needs to display.

**Why with a 1 pixel x and y increment isn't the number of each scroll calls not 540 and 759 rather than 342 and 660 for my specific case?**

Before trying to automate the calculations, I tried calling the scrollTop function multiple times with a parameter value starting with 0, and incrementing by 1 pixel in each successive call **(0, 1, 2, ... 10, 11, .., 20, etc.)**, and I found that the amount scrolled by each scroll call was not consistent.

I include this because with the inconsistency I found that I couldn't rely on the average scrolled amount by a few scroll calls to calculate the total number of calls needed to traverse the full distance of each div axis direction.

I can automate this with a loop that counts the number of repeated calls for each dimension, stopping counting for each direction when the respective scrollbar stops scrolling, and stopping looping when both scrollbars stop scrolling, but I'd rather not have to do this if there is a purely mathematical way to calculate the scaling values.  Besides, this would look odd to the user as the div contents jumped around each time it is loaded, especially for larger contents and slow the display.

**Does anyone know how to do this?**

Thanks.

Comment: `scrollHeight - clientHeight` will tell you how much you can scroll the div vertically.  `scrollTop` will tell you how far it is currently scrolled vertically.  The same for `scrollWidth - clientWidth` and `scrollLeft`.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but that's not really what I was asking about.  I've added a CodePen demo showing what I'm doing to calculate the scaling that I'm asking about.

Comment: Pretty sure that is what you were asking.  Please see my answer and if it is not correct, please update your answer with which value you are trying to calculate.  I  showed how to calculate Y-Scaling, Ave Scroll Y, and Ave Scroll X without needing to brute force the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to calculate yScaling, here you go:

```
var elem = $('#div2a').parent()[0]; // same as divScroller[0]
var yScaling = (elem.scrollHeight-elem.clientHeight) / (elem.scrollWidth-elem.clientWidth);
```

which for your divs, comes out to 1.9298245614035088.

If you want the values you are trying to calculate in "Ave Scroll Y" and "Ave Scroll X", then those values are 1 and 1/1.9298245614035088 which is 0.5181818181818182.

This is why the formula works:
Assume you have a viewport of 100px width, and the content inside that viewport is 400px.  When fully scrolled left, the scrollLeft will be 300px (400px - 100px).  300px of the 400px will be off the screen, and the last 100px will be visible inside the viewport.  That is why when you are trying to calculate the maximum value for scrollLeft, you use scrollWidth - clientWidth of the viewport (.scroller).  Do the same thing to calculate the maximum scrollTop, and the Y-Scaling is the ratio between those two numbers.

Comment: I Incorporated your answer into my demo and modified the Updated section to reflect this.  Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

Use currentScrollX and currentScrollY for setting current position of scrollbar and destinationScrollX and destinationScrollY for where you want to go

Then each animation loop runs the following to recalculate currentScrollX and currentScrollY

```
var speed = 20; // adjust accordingly

// Home into destination
currentScrollX += (destinationScrollX - currentScrollX) / speed;
currentScrollY += (destinationScrollY - currentScrollY) / speed;
```

To end scrolling simply do something like

```
if (Math.abs(destinationScrollX - currentScrollX) < 0.05 && Math.abs(destinationScrollY - currentScrollY) < 0.05) {
  currentScrollX = destinationScrollX;
  currentScrollY = destinationScrollY;
  // stop scrolling flag / code goes here
}

// At this point set scrollTop(currentScrollY) and scrollLeft(currentScrollX)
```

**Update**

If you want to scroll x and y a certain number of pixels in 30 frames based on their width / height then

```
 var scaleX = widthOfScrollingDiv / 30;
 var scaleY = heightOfScrollingDiv / 30;
```

You then animate for 30 frames and you'll reach the destination at the same time even if width and height aren't the same.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I'm asking about.  I've added a CodePen demo showing what I'm doing to calculate the scaling that I'm asking about.

Comment: John, Thanks for the update.  I'd add a third example to my demo to show how it works, but I don't quite understand how your method works, sorry.  To me, as I understand it, your suggestion appears to apply to the scrolling and animations of a desired duration.  I'm not trying to do that.  What I'm trying to do is pre-determine the amount that the vertical dimension needs to be scrolled when the horizontal dimension is scrolled, either automatically with the push of a button or when the user drags the mouse over the div's contents (not shown).  Robert McKee's method does this.